# How to rid space between footer and edge on both sides?

Tags: html, css

I want to span my footer the entire width of the page.

It doesn't sound like much but I'm spending a lot of time trying to fix it.

I have put margin 0 padding 0 to body and html.

My footer has a 100% width.

My footer is out of the container div and sits at the bottom of the page. It does not reach both sides of the page, left with a space between each side.

How do I fix this?

I have the following code in my css:

```
body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

footer {
clear: both;
padding: 0;
background-color: #ff0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: A short example of what you have tried would be helpful.

Comment: Can we have a fiddle or an example? its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

in Chrome, use the dev tools (press F12) to inspect the element and see what's causing the space.
in Firefox, you can use Firebug.

my guess is that it's a border on the footer, but without seeing the code, it's /just/ a guess.

Comment: thanks for the quick replies guys, i used firebug and identified it was the body creating padding. I did have margin: 0, padding: 0; in my style sheet but it didn't work. the only way i've got it working is by actually hard coding the same into the html e.g. <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"> is this what i'm suppose to do every time ?

Comment: No, the css should have been picked up.  The style sheet may not be getting included correctly in the page.